# How to Send ESP32 data to Winform app through websocket

Tags: c#, winforms, websocket, esp32

I want to send I2S data from ESP32 to a Winform app through websocket. I have tested sending data from ESP32 to a browser using websocket. Now I want to know how to connect c# Winform app to get these data through websocket.

Following is the code used to send data from ESP32 to browser.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <WebSocketsServer.h>
#include <driver/i2s.h>

const i2s_port_t I2S_PORT = I2S_NUM_0;
const char* ssid = "SSID";
const char* password = "PWD";

WebServer server(80);
WebSocketsServer webSocket = WebSocketsServer(81);

String JSONtxt;

#include "webpage.h"
void handleRoot()
{
 server.send(200,"text/html", webpageCont);
}
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(115200);

const i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
  // configuration                              
   };

const i2s_pin_config_t pin_config = {
 //pin configuration
}

server.on("/", handleRoot);
server.begin(); webSocket.begin();


void loop() 
{
webSocket.loop(); server.handleClient();

int32_t sample = 0;
int bytes_read = i2s_pop_sample(I2S_PORT, (char *)&sample, portMAX_DELAY); // no timeout
if (bytes_read > 0) {

String sampleString = String(sample);

JSONtxt = "{\"sample\":\""+sampleString+"\"}";
webSocket.broadcastTXT(JSONtxt);
}
}
```

webpage.h file is as follows

```
//=====================
const char webpageCont[] PROGMEM = 
R"=====(
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<title>ESP32 WebSocket Server</title>
<!---------------------------CSS-------------------------->
<style>
    
    body   {background-color:rgba(128,128,128,0.322); font-family:calibri}
    h1     {font-size: 40px; color: black; text-align: center}
    h2     {font-size: 30px; color: blue}
    
    div.h1 {background-color: whitesmoke;}
</style>
<!--------------------------HTML-------------------------->
<body>
    <h1><div class="h1">ESP32 WebSocket Server</div></h1>
    <h2>
        Level: <span style="color:rgb(216, 3, 3)" id="sample"></span>  
    </h2>
   </body>
<!----------------------JavaScript------------------------>
<script>
  InitWebSocket()
  function InitWebSocket()
  {
    websock = new WebSocket('ws://'+window.location.hostname+':81/');
    websock.onmessage=function(evt)
    {
       JSONobj = JSON.parse(evt.data);
       document.getElementById('sample').innerHTML = JSONobj.sample;
       var sample = parseInt(JSONobj.sample);
      
    }
  }
</script>
</html>
)=====";
```

Comment: Why are you using port 81 instead of port 80?

Comment: port 80 is used by server to keep listening to coming sockets websocket server port 81 used to send request to server socket @jdweng

Comment: The server has to be listening on port 81 for code to work, port 81 also needs to be unblocked by virus checkers and firewalls, and the roles have to be set to accept connections on port 81.